# CMS_verify fails if signature issuer differs from certificate issuer

Tags: security, openssl, pkcs#7

When trying to verify a signed data structure using

```
openssl smime -verify -in EF_SOD.PEM -inform pem -noverify
```

I get this error:

```
Verification failure
10280:error:2107C080:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_get0_signers:signer certificate not found:pk7_smime.c:378:
```

It seems that the identity of the signature issuer is not literally the same as the identity of the embedded certificate issuer.

These are the two issuers:

```
issuer: CN=CSCAEC_BE_3, OU=FEDERAL PUBLIC SERVICE FOREIGN AFFAIRS BELGIUM, O=KINGDOM OF BELGIUM, C=BE
issuer: C=BE, O=KINGDOM OF BELGIUM, OU=FEDERAL PUBLIC SERVICE FOREIGN AFFAIRS BELGIUM, CN=CSCAEC_BE_3
```

According to RFC 5280, the two names have have the exact same attributes in the exact same order.
Does this mean the data structure is corrupt?

Originally, I want to use `CMS_verify` in code to do the verification:

```
nRet = CMS_verify(pCMS, certs, NULL, NULL, NULL, CMS_NO_SIGNER_CERT_VERIFY);
```

Is there a way to parametrise the function so that it will be successful?

Thank you!

Comment: *"According to RFC 5280, the two names have have the exact same attributes in the exact same order...."* - Regarding the names, I believe you should follow the Subjec/Issuer pairs. Regarding the rules on "certificate equivalence" in PKIX, I believe the controlling document is [RFC 4158 - Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certification Path Building](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4158). I'm not sure what controls PKCS#7 or CMS. Maybe the RFC provides a normative reference.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is it safe to just copy the issuer from the certificate to the signer block and then use cms_verify? If I do that and then call `openssl smime -verify -in EF_SOD_MOD.PEM -inform pem -noverify` I get a successful verification.